# Grub shows some time and does show some time

Tags: grub2, gnome, 14.04

I have only ubuntu-gnome 14.04 on my laptop when i am booting into my system some times only show's the grub. Any way I don't need the grub any more but, if I have to get into generic mode to reset my password then what should I do

GRUB_DEFAULT=0

GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0

GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true

GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0597]
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: add the main output from `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` also add the output `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`

Comment: can u get it more clearly

Comment: open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and add the outputs from my previous comment

Comment: added the output in the question

Comment: read my re-edited answer, hope that works for you

Comment: This is a grub question why is it tagged with GNOME?

Comment: @TaylorBioniks good notice, I missed it when edited it, just re-edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncomment this line from your grub file:

GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0

then change your:

GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

to:

GRUB_TIMEOUT=0

after:

```
sudo update-grub

sudo reboot
```

P.S.

You can backup your old settings from current grub file in case you will change your mind and want to use it again.

Comment: Thank you very much for ur help and ur patience in even editing my question. Can i know where can i contact for help mail or something like that and it worked

Comment: I'm glad if it worked for you, if you're satisfied with my answer don't forget to accept it. Cheers.